# What is the minipage equivalent of `width=\linewidth` for \includegraphics

Tags: minipage, width, includegraphics

`width=\linewidth` is acceptable input option to `\includegraphics`, but is not acceptable as input to `minipage`. What can we replace `X` with so that `\begin{minipage}{X}` has a similair width setting to `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{file_name}`?

---

The following code is meant to create a framed figure. It almost works except that I do not want the width of the minipage to be hard-coded in to be 12 cm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{12 cm}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{solution_count_satisfiability}
            \caption{caption}
        \label{label}
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `\centering` instruction is redundant as the `minipage` is supposed to take up the full width of the textblock.

Comment: please use `example-image` as the example so people can run your code.

Comment: @Mico: The `\centering` is actually required as the `minipage` is inside `\fbox` which makes it a little wider as the line width.

Comment: @MartinScharrer but `\centering` does not center boxes that are wider than the line width, it will be overfull on the right margin

Comment: @MartinScharrer - Indeed, my comment about `\centering` being redundant was based on the assumption (educate guess?!) that `12cm` was the OP's approximation of `\textwidth` in a LaTeX document that uses the `article` document class and a font size of `10pt`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, my mistake. I confused it with `\centerline` or `adjustbox`s `center` key.

Comment: Unlike minipage, \fbox does not have a fixed width, but expands to fit whatever is inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your question is about, simply changing `12cm` with `\linewidth` does it, and, as David already pointed out, you need to subtract the separation and line width of `\fbox` from it, otherwise the box will be larger then the line width.
Also `\fbox{<linebreak>` will cause a space be added, which will push the image a little to the left, so you need to mask it with a comment: `\fbox{%`.

The simplest way would be using `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}% loads graphicx

\usepackage{mwe}% for example text only

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,fbox,center}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{label}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

As Mico stated already, the centering (here done with the `center` key) is not really needed if the content is already as wide as the line. I added it for good measure as you might change the width later.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\includegraphics` requires the string `width=` to proceed the width argument. However, `minipage` does not require that input arguments be labeled. It not only doesn't require it; it doesn't support it. We simply pass in the input argument without a label:  `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}`

Comment: are you going to post this question/answer for every command that takes a length? why just mention `minipage` not `\parbox` or `tabular*` or `\makebox` ?

Comment: If you use `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` in the code in the question the box will be too wide by 2\fboxsep+2\\fboxrule+2 word spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`1.0\textwidth`

Full first line: `\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}`.

Of course, for example `\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}` sets the width to 40% of
the normal text width.